# Custom template binding on sortable elements based on condition (Knockout.js Sortable)

Tags: jquery-ui, knockout.js, knockout-sortable

I have an observable array of items which are made draggable/droppable using the Knockout sortable plugin. I am able to apply a custom template binding on the elements as per the [doc](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) using following piece of code.

```
<div style="border-width:0;" data-bind="sortable: {template: 'customTemplate', data: observableArray}">
```

My requirement is to use different templates for different items in the array based on certain condition applied to the item property. For example, if we have a property called 'status' for each item in the observable array, I want to bind 'template1' if status is true else 'template2'.

I am able to achieve the same for arrays which can be traversed using foreach loop in ko, but unable to do the same for sortable array since it does not allow to use foreach. Can someone suggest a solution/workaround to the same?

UPDATE: I was able to apply custom binding in the same template based on condition but it lead to a strange error where the element gets cloned in the parent container while dragging and dropping it into a target container. Demo can be seen here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UdXr4/815/)

I have applied different style to students based on name but on dropping the student to a table, it gets cloned in the parent table as well. What can be the possible issue?

Note: I do not want to bind conditional css to my elements, I want to differentiate the way elements render, based on condition. Example - Going by the table seating example, if I have properties name, age and class for students object, I just want to show name for few students while all 3 properties for some as can be seen in the example fiddle.

Comment: well if you need to use two template you can try this on individual template code `<!-- ko if:status --> //code <!--/ko--> ` &  `<!-- ko if:! status() --> //code <!--/ko--> ` . cheers

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/jyFTX/5/ . cheers

Comment: Thanks for your response @supercool. Even I tried doing the same by applying conditional HTML in the same template earlier. It worked fine but strangely, when I drag and drop the element in a container, it creates a copy in the parent container as well instead of simply moving the item to target container.

Comment: ooh i see can you make a fiddle sort of to reproduce your issue . so it will be easy to figure why .

Comment: Hi @supercool, edited the answer with a fiddle.

Comment: try this which should work as expected http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/UdXr4/814/ . cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we can fix the issue using conditional `css` binding

**View :**

```
<script type="text/html" id="customTmpl">
        <div  data-bind="css:{'one': name() === 'Bobby' ? true : false ,'two': name() != 'Bobby' ? true : false } ">
            <p data-bind="text: name"></p>
        </div>
</script>
```

Instead of going for a conditional containerless `if` we can simply avoid it and do it with conditional `css` binding .

Working fiddler **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/UdXr4/814)**

Documentation on `css` available **[here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html)**

Comment: Thanks @supercool. But this does not solve my issue, since I don't just want to change the css for div, I want to change the inner elements of div as well. For example, if I have properties name and age for students, I want to show both name and age for some students, and only name for some as you can checkout in the updated fiddle.

Comment: the you should be doing this which works fine http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/UdXr4/816/ . cheers

Comment: Thanks @supercool, It works fine. I found an alternate way to make this work as well. All that was needed to be done was to separate the sortable element div and the template div as can be seen in the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/UdXr4/817/

Comment: just a advice its always better to avoid conditions and extra html .

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to make it work by adding conditional knockout code in a single template and separating the template div from the sortable div as can be seen in the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UdXr4/817/).

The conditional script was written as below:

```
<script type="text/html" id="customTmpl">
 <!-- ko if: name() == 'Bobby' -->
    <div style="background-color: red; margin:4px;">
        <p data-bind="text: name"></p>
        <p data-bind="text: gender"></p>
    </div>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if:name() != 'Bobby' -->
    <div style="background-color: yellow; margin:4px;">
        <p data-bind="text: name"></p>
    </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

The sortable and the template divs were separated as:

```
<div class="seats" data-bind="sortable: {data: students, allowDrop: $root.isTableFull }">
        <div style="padding:0; border-width:0" data-bind="template:'customTmpl'"></div>
    </div>
```

Hope it helps :)